# debian: Non-english font support for chrome

Tags: debian, fonts, chrome, backports

I wasn't able to view any non-english characters in chrome. It just appeared as squares. When I accidentally ran`apt-get -t stretch-backports upgrade` It somehow got fixed.

Now I renistalled the debian and would like to get only that specific package from backports. What might be the exact package?

**Kernel version version:** 4.19.0-0.bpo.2-amd64 (backports)

**Chrome version:** 72.0.3626.119

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one big meta package [fonts-indic](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/fonts-indic), but there are also lots of [other indian font packages](https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=stretch&arch=amd64&searchon=all&keywords=font%20indian).
Can't really tell which one you are looking for. But none of these are in stretch-backports.

- all fonts in [stretch](https://packages.debian.org/en/stretch/fonts/)
- all fonts in [stretch-backports](https://packages.debian.org/en/stretch-backports/fonts/)